# Getting result only for a specified id in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-permission

I have a little problem. My code is working, but I think I'm not doing it the proper way.

In my GradeController i have this code:

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    if(auth()->user()->hasRole('Student')) {
        $subjects = Subject::all();

        return view('grades.student.index', compact('subjects'));
    }
}
```

And in my view I'm getting Grades which belong to a specified user this way:

```
@foreach($subject->grades->where('student_id', '=', auth()->user()->id) as $grade)
<span class="badge badge-primary">
    {{ $grade->value }}
</span>@endforeach
```

Is here, I mean Laravel, any better way to do this? Because I think that getting all Grades which belong to a Subject and then look for ID is not very "effective".

Have a good day.

Comment: One idea: You can take a look at Laravel Scopes where you can move this `->where('student_id', '=', $userId)` part there just to clean up. Also I wouldn't suggest querying in the blade file, I'd say do it in your backend and pass to `return view()` part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `with()` eager loading helper, with a closure which will filter the `subject`'s 'grades` based on the grade belonging to the logged in user:

```
$subjects = Subject::with(['grades' => function($query) {
    $query->where('student_id', auth()->user()->id);
}])->get();
```

Note the removal of `, '=',` in the `->where()` clause. It does not need this argument if checking if equal to.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller `index()` you can make a middleware instead of doing this check `auth()->user()->hasRole('Student')` many times, buy if you will check only once here it will be fine what you did.

```
public function index()
{
    // refactoring 
    return view('grades.student.index', ['subject' => Subject::all()]);
}
```

Also its not good to make a query in your blade file, so you can pass `grades` directly from you controller

```
public function index()
{
    return view('grades.student.index', [
        'grades' => Grade::where('student_id', auth()->id())->get()
    ]);
}
```

In `index` blade file you can now use:

```
@foreach($grades as $grade)
<span class="badge badge-primary">
    {{ $grade->value }}
</span>
// you can get the subject from $grade->subject
@endforeach
```

Comment: This does work, however if there is any `Subject` data required (such as the name of the `Subject`), the `Grade` collection will not have this data.

Comment: @thisiskelvin Yes, indeed :D